# How can I connect a USB drive in a virtual machine running on Windows 2012 server

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I have a windows 2012 server running. My virtual machine is a windows SBS 2008 server. Physically I can connect a USB to my Windows 2012 server, but I don't know how to connect the USB to the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the USB drive, then look in the virtual machine settings to see if you can create another "virtual hard drive" that is mapped with the USB drive.

Alternately, most virtual machine hosts have a way to bring arbitrary USB devices into a VM. Look in the "USB" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Hyper-V doesn't support USB forwarding. So if you use Hyper-V for virtualization the only option is to add your USB drive as storage to your VM.

- On your host, disable the drive in **Disk Management** (diskmgmt.msc)
- in the VM preferences, add a new hard disk and choose **physical hard disk** and your usb drive
- in the VM check in **Disk Management** that the new drive is marked active

see also: http://blogs.technet.com/b/hollis/archive/2012/02/21/accessing-usb-drives-in-a-hyper-v-vm.aspx